# Making a div the same size as it's sibling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div the same size as it's sibling img.

http://jsfiddle.net/25Gnc/

On the second image:

```
<div class="crop-fade"></div>
```

This fade should be the same size as the img.

Comment: For me it is (Firefox 29). What browser are you using?

Comment: looks like there is a slight overlap of about 3 or 4px

Comment: That would be the inline whitespace. See the answer from @Liam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your img and make sure you clear margin and padding around the image http://jsfiddle.net/25Gnc/11/

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
}
```